# SQL Request error on ubuntu but not on windows

Tags: mysql, sql, windows, ubuntu, select

i have two SQL servers for a website, one for test on Windows and an other on Ubuntu.

The following command: `SELECT * FROM utilisateur WHERE mail="bla.bla@bla.fr" AND MdP=PASSWORD("Pass&word45");` don't run on Ubuntu

I have this error code:
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '("Pass&word45")' at line 1`

Thank you for reading

Comment: that function was removed with version 5.7.5 check which version you are running

Comment: Please include your MySQL version and the language and method you use to submit the query from the website. You have an ampersand in your code, but the error result shows it properly in theory. Consider executing this command directly on the servers in question to see if it's purely syntactical vs translation on the way to the server (or the deprecation of the PASSWORD command as mentioned by nbk, of course).